# How to make a website responsive to your android mobile screen size?

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to convert my website into an android application. I am using using Bootstrap for responsiveness of my site.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<div class='row'>";

    echo"<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3'>";
        echo"<strong>".$row["BookID"]."</strong>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-7 col-7'>";
            echo "<div class='row'><strong>".$row["Bookname"]."</strong></div>";
            echo "<div class='row'>".$row["Authorname"]." [ ".$row["Edition"]." ]</div>"; 
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-2'>";
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='bookids[]' value='".$row["BookID"]."'>";
    echo "</div></div><hr>";

}
echo "<br>
<input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' value='Submit Renewal'></center></div>";
}
```

The shown below is the screenshots of my output in browser and in my android application.

`browser output shown below`

[image: browser output looks like this]

`android app output is shown below` 
[image: my app looks like this]

kindly help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Not sure but there is break in your code , some browsers smartly optimize your web-page , but some don't . Please review your code whether you are completing your tags properly , using while or for loops  check all the components inside them are started and ended properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

inside the `<head></head>` tag

And you need to be sure that you are not setting fixed width or height on some of the elements in your page